# FFMpeg removes the video stream unintentionally

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg, video, media-info

I used the following ffmpeg command to downscale a video. But surprisingly the output did not have any video stream, just an audio-only output.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "input.mov" -c:v libx264 -vf scale=640:252 -c:a aac "output.mp4"
```

Following is the sample input file: [input.mov](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11eH4Hv-muhm3UOcsUYVbLH69H-UJ6p_w/view?usp=sharing)

**PS:** Noticed the following values in the `Mediainfo` of the input video which seemed strange.

1. Total general duration is `3min44s` but Video stream duration is `1ms`
2. Overall bitrate is `268 kb/s` but video stream bitrate is `16.7 Gb/s`
3. Video frame rate is abnormally high `5616000 fps`.

The strange thing is FFMpeg's output log indicates there's a video stream in the output(`Stream #0:0`) when there is none. Can be checked on playing the output as well as by running `Mediainfo` on the generated output.

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x12b7040b0] st: 1 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x12b7040b0] st: 1 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 0.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/input.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2022-08-21T23:05:50.000000Z
  Duration: 00:03:44.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 267 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 2048x808, 25 fps, 25 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-08-21T23:05:50.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-08-21T23:04:31.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x11b60cbc0] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x11b60cbc0] profile High, level 2.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x11b60cbc0] 264 - core 164 r3095 baee400 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=8 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/Users/output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x252, q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-08-21T23:05:50.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-08-21T23:04:31.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 aac
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=    1836kB time=00:03:44.61 bitrate=  67.0kbits/s speed=96.5x    
video:0kB audio:1794kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.339867%
[aac @ 0x11b60dd00] Qavg: 8288.993
```

**Ask:** What is the cause of no video stream in the output? And how can it be fixed? My goal is to get the exact same video, just downscaled to the mentioned dimensions.

Comment: It seems ffmpeg can't find any key frames, also the whole video seem to only 1 frame.

Comment: Is there any possible solution using ffmpeg to just get the downscaled output?